# Google sheets listing function Needed

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to create a function that list the name of any cells in each column A-F whose values are equal to 0. EX: I would like A:32 to display the names of any cells whose values are less than 1 of equal to zero.

[Google Sheets document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjmqC.png)

I would really appreciate the help

Thanks!

I have tried using a Filter function, but it does not want to list cell names.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below function will see if value is over zeron, then get the row and column of the cell and leverage the Address function to get the "name" as you call it.

After that, it uses ToCol, to make a single list, then filter by not equal to false.

Finally, textjoin puts everything in a single cell. You can change the splitter to be something besides `;`

```
=textjoin(";",,Let(allData,A1:F30,oneColData,tocol(arrayFormula(if(allData>0,
ADDRESS(row(alldata),column(alldata),4),false))),filter(oneColData,oneColData<>FALSE)))
```

Screenshot on smaller range showing result...

[image]